# Password protect files and/or folders on a usb stick

Tags: usb

I want to make secure [deaddrop](http://www.deadrops.com/). I want everyone to be able to store files that only a person with the password can access. *I need to lock individual files & folders, no the entire drive.*

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use file-level encryption on the files/folders you want to secure, rather than just encrypting the whole USB drive. You can use any available file encryption utilities to do this. The receipient will then need to know how to unencrypt the files.

I'm not an expert here, but there are free tools available to do this type of encryption. One example: https://www.aescrypt.com/